# Redux saga: internals of how redux-saga works

Tags: redux, middleware, redux-saga

I know that a redux middleware sits between an action getting dispatched and reducer getting called. Understanding redux-thunk was easy compared to redux-saga. I understand generators and how they are being used to write code that depends on async calls to be written as if code is synchronous. I also know that generator becomes a consumer in this model. Generator yields instructions to redux-saga middleware. Middleware handles the request and gives back result. What I don't get is how saga middleware is possible in a single threaded execution. Also why we call run root saga method? Is it a setup method or does it really start running sagas? Since we can dispatch actions from sagas by using put effect, does it take the whole execution back to where middleware started. Can someone clarify how the whole handling of saga happen?

Comment: It is possible in single-thread becuase of web apis and event loop (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) same as any other async stuff in javascript. `sagaMiddleware.run`  really starts sagas, although you usually start with setting up your own stuff (like starting watcher sagas etc.). And yes, when using `put` effect the action makes its way to redux and any other middleware that might interested - including again redux-saga.

Comment: @MartinKadlec Since no action is dispatched yet, why run starts running sagas?

Comment: 99% of the times, it is used to start watcher sagas. When using redux-saga library you have to create a watcher that will listen for the actions you want (`yield takeEvery(ACTION, handleActionSaga)`). Otherwise when someone would eventually dispatch an action there would be no way to handle it. Other than that there might be some other stuff to do, like reading data from localStorage and putting them to state, fetching initial bulk data from backend etc.

Comment: @MartinKadlec so the watcher sagas are run by web api? Otherwise they would block everything else, right?

Comment: Watcher is just a saga generator that yields effects. But the saga library that consumes and handles the effects is then using web apis internally. One example of webapi is the `setTimeout` function in javascript that you use run something sometime in future.

Comment: Another webapi are DOM events (like onClick). Those are not used by redux-saga directly. But for example by React. Then when user clicks on some element, you will dispatch an action and by doing so you let redux-saga know to do something. This is all more about how javascript works rather the redux-saga.

Comment: @MartinKadlec I know how web apis and single threaded model work. What I don't get is in the saga that you start you yield takeEvery to call a certain method when a certain action is dispatched, but this happens when run root saga happens. Then something has to monitor actions constantly to know that action is of interest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185516/discussion-between-martin-kadlec-and-neo).